Quantum oracle based on MCX gates
I am working on a quantum implementation of a fuzzy inference engine. This system is based on a quantum oracle which fulfills the reconstruction of the rule base. In the current implementation (image 1), the quantum oracle is implemented by means of MCX gates. Unfortunately this implementation has some strong limitations:

the sequentiality strongly reduce the theoretical advantage of this algorithm with respect to the classical counterpart;

MCX gates cause the circuit to be too deep for an execution on a real backend.


With that said, I would love if you could suggest me some ways to improve this system.
So far I have tried different approaches: error mitigation; reduction of the depth by means of v-chain implementation of MCX gates; parallelization of the circuit 1 to circuit 2. Nothing worked.


